# How to read in multiple characters from a file, multiply the character into a grid and print back to a new file

Tags: java

I am trying to read multiple characters from a file multiply each character so that when I print it to a new file they appear in a grid like format.

```
    int num = 4;
    String fileStr = "";

    scnrIn.useDelimiter("zzzzzzzzz");

    while(scnrIn.hasNextLine()) {
        fileStr = scnrIn.nextLine();

        char[] charArray = fileStr.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < Math.sqrt(num); ++j) {
                writer.write(charArray[i]);
                for(int k = 1; k < Math.sqrt(num); ++k) {
                    writer.write(charArray[i]);
            }
                writer.newLine();
                writer.flush();
        }
        }
    }


}
```

}

If my txt file contains the characters @#$ and my mulitplier is 4 I expect the new txt file to print:

```
@@##$$
@@##$$
```

but instead I get:

```
@@
@@
##
##
$$
$$
```

I feel like the issue is tied to writer.newLine(); but if I take it away or comment it out then it won't print it in a grid. I am not sure how to get around the need for a new line to print in a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to the nesting of your for loops. If you follow what your code is doing, you are writing out the one current character at `i` in a grid and then going on to the next character in the `charArray`.

Instead what you should be doing is going by the rows and printing out the current character's number of columns for each character before going to a new line. This mainly requires switching the two most outer for loops and then fixing how often you call write.

Here is the code working as expected:

```
int num = 4;    
int cols = (int) Math.sqrt(num); //easier to read the code when stored in a variable
int rows = cols;

String fileStr = "";

scnrIn.useDelimiter("zzzzzzzzz");

while(scnrIn.hasNextLine()) {
    fileStr = scnrIn.nextLine();
    char[] charArray = fileStr.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
            char curChar = charArray[j]; //this is the current character we want to write out for the number of columns times

            for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                writer.write(curChar);
            }
        }
        writer.newLine(); //create a new line after every row
    }
    writer.flush(); //better to only flush output when fully done
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got hung up on the wrong places. Thank you for your assistance.